# Стилизация checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, веб-дизайн

Как убрать `border-radius` и сделать свой `background-color` в checkbox без js?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/154719/

Comment: Лучше кастомизировать не чекбокс, а его лэйбл.